# Can anyone solve this problem called the "Three Gods"?

Tags: logical-deduction

**Three gods True, False, and Random are called, in no particular order. True always speaks truly, False always speaks falsely, but whether Random speaks truly or falsely is a completely random matter. Your task is to determine the identities of A, B, and C by asking three yes-no questions; each question must be put to exactly one god. The gods understand English, but will answer all questions in their own language, in which the words for yes and no are da and ja, in some order. You do not know which word means which.**

Is there a solution to this problem? What is it? I can't seem to get anything.

Comment: This is a very famous puzzle, hope that someone will post the answer/link/ a similar question. (a bit busy )

Comment: The answer is at  http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/2665/22648